# What part of the Linux kernel determines the execution order of userland apps?

Tags: linux, boot, users, linux-kernel

Stripping the source, I can't pinpoint which part of the kernel sets and manages the userland apps, and how it does it.

For example, in the Linux main source, is the procedure have options to set boot order, and app load order prior to manual determination?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you're asking. Are you looking for the scheduler?

Comment: Sounds like the scheduler to me (or...).  Note that the kernel only really ever starts one userland app itself, `init` -- everything else then has `init` as an ancestor. I.e., the stuff you are talking about at boot is done entirely in userland, not by the kernel. So (...or con't) maybe you are actually asking about the init system and how services, etc, are started at boot?

Comment: You're looking for `/etc/init.`d and the different run levels like `/etc/rc2.d` `/etc/rc3.d` usw. usf.?

Comment: Do you mean at boot time, or do you mean what decides what will execute on a single processor when multiple processes all want to run at once?

Answer (score 2):

No part of the kernel does it.  The kernel starts PID 1, `init`.  That process is responsible for starting whatever other userland apps are going to run.  How `init` goes about doing that depends on what [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) you're running.  Common init systems are the classic [SysV init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style), and newer systems like [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) and [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).